# Webview2 ExecuteScriptAsync to click submit button

Tags: javascript

Please see below this HTML code for understanding:
[image]

```html
<button type="submit" 
        class="btn btn-blue btn_login" 
        value="login" 
        ng-click=" login('/checkin')" 
        ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid">
         login 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" 
              style="font-size:14px" aria-hidden="true">
        </span>
</button
```

I want to click the Button, but the code I'm using doesn't work,Help me, please

```cs
 WebView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-blue btn_login').submit();")
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a node list. And the button doesn't have a function named `submit`. It has `click` instead.

Comment: @Eldar Can you show me from example code please..

Answer (score 0):

According to your HTML something like below should work for you.

```
WebView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-blue btn_login')[0].click();")
```

Or instead you can submit the form like below :

```
WebView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('loginForm').submit();")
```

Above approach assumes that your form has the id `loginForm`